# Using AFNetworking or JSONKit to talk to a Node.js express webserver

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking, jsonkit

If all I wanted to do with a webserver was to request data and send commands from an iPhone app, all I'd need for that is AFJSONRequestOperation, correct? Why are some people also using JSONKit with AFNetworking? If I use JSONKit then do I still need to use AFNetworking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a JSON parsing library (like JSONKit) if you are deploying to < iOS 5.

`AFNetworking` does all the networking stuff
`JSONKit` does the parsing/encoding of JSON on < iOS 5

From [AFNetworking git](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

> AFNetworking requires either iOS 4.0 and above, or Mac OS 10.6 and above.
>
> AFNetworking uses NSJSONSerialization if it is available. If your app targets a platform where this class is not available you can include one of the following JSON libraries to your project for AFNetworking to automatically detect and use.
>
> - JSONKit
> - SBJson
> - YAJL

Comment: I ran the same program in the iOS 4.3 simulator, and it didn't need any extra JSON libraries to work.